# Is there a function f(n) that returns the n:th combination in an ordered list of combinations without repetition?

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

Combinations without repetitions look like this, when the number of elements to choose from (n) is 5 and elements chosen (r) is 3:

```
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
0 2 3
0 2 4
0 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```

As n and r grows the amount of combinations gets large pretty quickly. For (n,r) = (200,4) the number of combinations is 64684950.

It is easy to iterate the list with r nested for-loops, where the initial iterating value of each for loop is greater than the current iterating value of the for loop in which it is nested, as in this jsfiddle example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/wHWK5o

What I would like is a function that calculates only one combination based on its index. Something like this:

```
tuple combination(i,n,r) {
  return [combination with index i, when the number of elements to choose from is n and elements chosen is r]
```

Does anyone know if this is doable?

Comment: Thanks, spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the first element of the result. The value of that element depends on the number of combinations you can get with smaller elements. For each such smaller first element, the number of combinations with first element *k* is *n* − *k* − 1 choose *r* − 1, with potentially some of-by-one corrections. So you would sum over a bunch of binomial coefficients. Wolfram Alpha [can help you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(n-i-1)+choose+(r-1)+for+i+from+0+to+k) compute such a sum, but the result still has a binomial coefficient in it. Solving for the largest *k* such that the sum doesn't exceed your given index *i* is a computation you can't do with something as simple as e.g. a square root. You need a loop to test possible values, e.g. like this:

```py
def first_naive(i, n, r):
  """Find first element and index of first combination with that first element.

  Returns a tuple of value and index.

  Example: first_naive(8, 5, 3) returns (1, 6) because the combination with
  index 8 is [1, 3, 4] so it starts with 1, and because the first combination
  that starts with 1 is [1, 2, 3] which has index 6.
  """
  s1 = 0
  for k in range(n):
    s2 = s1 + choose(n - k - 1, r - 1)
    if i < s2:
      return k, s1
    s1 = s2
```

You can reduce the O(*n*) loop iterations to O(log *n*) steps using bisection, which is particularly relevant for large *n*. In that case I find it easier to think about numbering items from the *end* of your list. In the case of *n* = 5 and *r* = 3 you get `choose(2, 2)=1` combinations starting with 2, `choose(3,2)=3` combinations starting with 1 and `choose(4,2)=6` combinations starting with 0. So in the general `choose(n,r)` binomial coefficient you increase the *n* with each step, and keep the *r*. Taking into account that `sum(choose(k,r) for k in range(r,n+1))` [can be simplified](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k+choose+r+for+k+from+r+to+n) to `choose(n+1,r+1)`, you can eventually come up with bisection conditions like the following:

```py
def first_bisect(i, n, r):
  nCr = choose(n, r)
  k1 = r - 1
  s1 = nCr
  k2 = n
  s2 = 0
  while k2 - k1 > 1:
    k3 = (k1 + k2) // 2
    s3 = nCr - choose(k3, r)
    if s3 <= i:
      k2, s2 = k3, s3
    else:
      k1, s1 = k3, s3
  return n - k2, s2
```

Once you know the first element to be *k*, you also know the index of the first combination with that same first element (also returned from my function above). You can use the difference between that first index and your actual index as input to a recursive call. The recursive call would be for *r* − 1 elements chosen from *n* − *k* − 1. And you'd add *k* + 1 to each element from the recursive call, since the top level returns values starting at 0 while the next element has to be greater than *k* in order to avoid duplication.

```py
def combination(i, n, r):
  """Compute combination with a given index.

  Equivalent to list(itertools.combinations(range(n), r))[i].

  Each combination is represented as a tuple of ascending elements, and
  combinations are ordered lexicograplically.

  Args:
    i: zero-based index of the combination
    n: number of possible values, will be taken from range(n)
    r: number of elements in result list
  """
  if r == 0:
    return []
  k, ik = first_bisect(i, n, r)
  return tuple([k] + [j + k + 1 for j in combination(i - ik, n - k - 1, r - 1)])
```

I've got a [complete working example](http://ideone.com/MTOEJQ), including an implementation of `choose`, more detailed doc strings and tests for some basic assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great way to decrease the required number of iterations to reach the index of a given combination, but since the suggestion is essentially the same as N. Wouda's and that answer came before yours, I will mark that answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: @Martin: Sure, if you don't need bisection, N. Wouda's answer is totally worth being accepted. I've now augmented my answer with some code snippets to help future readers, particularly since the bisection approach leaves ample room for off-by-one and wrong-sign errors so it took me a few tries to get that right.

Comment: Yeah ok so that is an insanely fast way of solving this for practically any n,r. Going to remark this as the accepted answer, since this is the answer that anyone having this problem is looking for. Hats off to you.

Comment: Is there a way to expand this to slice the combinations? I.e. return all of the combinations between index `i` and index `j` `list(itertools.combinations())[i:j]`

Comment: @Gaberocksall: Once you have the first combination from the algorithm above, getting the next one is fairly straightforward. Try incrementing the last element. If that reaches `n`, increment the position one before and then make the last poison one bigger than that. If the penultimate element reaches `n-1` then increment the position before that. Keep moving the increment position left until you find a position you can increment. If this is not clear enough this night be best discussed in a separate question. I'd expect such a question to already exist, but don't have the time to look now.

Answer (score 5):

You would first need to impose some sort of ordering on the set of all combinations available for a given `n` and `r`, such that a linear index makes sense. I suggest we agree to keep our combinations in increasing order (or, at least, the indices of the individual elements), as in your example. How then can we go from a linear index to a combination?

Let us first build some intuition for the problem. Suppose we have `n = 5` (e.g. the set `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`) and `r = 3`. How many unique combinations are there in this case? The answer is of course `5-choose-3`, which evaluates to `10`. Since we will sort our combinations in increasing order, consider for a minute how many combinations remain once we have exhausted all those starting with `0`. This must be `4-choose-3`, or `4` in total. In such a case, if we are looking for the combination at index `7` initially, this implies we must subtract `10 - 4 = 6` and search for the combination at index `1` in the set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. This process continues until we find a new index that is smaller than this offset.

Once this process concludes, we know the first digit. Then we only need to determine the remaining `r - 1` digits! The algorithm thus takes shape as follows (in Python, but this should not be too difficult to translate),

```py
from math import factorial


def choose(n, k):
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))


def combination_at_idx(idx, elems, r):
    if len(elems) == r:
        # We are looking for r elements in a list of size r - thus, we need
        # each element.
        return elems

    if len(elems) == 0 or len(elems) < r:
        return []

    combinations = choose(len(elems), r)    # total number of combinations
    remains = choose(len(elems) - 1, r)     # combinations after selection

    offset = combinations - remains

    if idx >= offset:       # combination does not start with first element
        return combination_at_idx(idx - offset, elems[1:], r)

    # We now know the first element of the combination, but *not* yet the next
    # r - 1 elements. These need to be computed as well, again recursively.
    return [elems[0]] + combination_at_idx(idx, elems[1:], r - 1)
```

Test-driving this with your initial input,

```py
N = 5
R = 3

for idx in range(choose(N, R)):
    print(idx, combination_at_idx(idx, list(range(N)), R))
```

I find,

```
0 [0, 1, 2]
1 [0, 1, 3]
2 [0, 1, 4]
3 [0, 2, 3]
4 [0, 2, 4]
5 [0, 3, 4]
6 [1, 2, 3]
7 [1, 2, 4]
8 [1, 3, 4]
9 [2, 3, 4]
```

Where the linear index is zero-based.

Comment: Nice, through answer, thanks! This is conceptually spot on, so thank you for making it clear. I think that the number of recursions required for large numbers of combinations is forbidding, but that can probably be fixed by iterating instead of recursing. Thanks again!

Comment: @Martin: Iteration can be done pretty easily here rather than recursion. That's what my code did, but this answer appeared before I was ready and it covers most of my ideas. So I'll not post my code but did upvote this one instead.